# How to navigate to "Add Products" standard page from LWC?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, opportunity, button-overrides

Upon standard opportunity creation, a standard `Add Products` page is shown to the user(if the checkbox in `Setup>Opportunity Settings` is checked). However, we have overridden the standard opportunity creation button with a custom lightning web component. After the record is saved via that component, I again want the user to navigate to the `Add Products` page. How can this functionality be achieved? The Add Products functionality works fine if I do not override the standard Opportunity creation button.

Comment: Hi Ayush, have you found a solution to it ?